# Opening app through Python causes ERROR.SQL error 03701

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to automate logging into a desktop application via Python.

So far, no matter how I rewrite startup code it results in the SQL error 03701. It works without issue when I click the shortcut and even when I launch the .exe in Command Prompt.

I have tried

```
target_dir = r"C:\Imaginra"
subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(target_dir, "Amtech.exe"))

subprocess.call(["C:\\Imaginra\\Amtech.exe"])

pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Imaginra\Amtech.exe")
```

I have even tried launching a .bat that then launches Amtech.exe. That still results in error 03701 when I click the login button.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I had to run my .py file from the same folder as the .exe. This appears to have solved it.